# Execution failed with app:processDebugGoogleServices'

Tags: android, firebase, dependencies, google-cloud-firestore, gradle-plugin

I have been trying to add retrieve some of my images from Firebase firestore. After I added the dependencies I have the following error

> "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'. >
>   Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the
>   google-services plugin (information about the latest version is
>   available at
>   https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/)
>   or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 10.0.1."

This is my module app gradle

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.rimapps.charpapers"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions{
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'

    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.+'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.1'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is my project gradle

```html
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
        //classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Please help to solve this problem I have tried all I could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve this, you need to use the same version for dependencies like this:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.4.2'
```

As you probably see, now all dependencies have `11.4.2` version.

Answer (score 1):

To solve your issue, change this:

```
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.2'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.6.2'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.6.2'
```

[**THE FIREBASE VERSION IS:  11.6.2** - November 27, 2017](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android?hl=pt-br)

But you should update your gradle file:

```
... dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
...
```

And now, change the `compile` for `implementation`:

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.2'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.6.2'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.6.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Read Error Log**

> "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'. >
>   Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the
>   google-services plugin

You should use **SAME** version **(Version conflict)** . Use **`11.4.2`**

```
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.4.2'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.4.2'
```

After that, **`Clean-Rebuild-Run.`**

**FYI**

[**`SDK Version 11.6.2`**](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android?hl=pt-br) has been launched. You can use **`11.6.2`** version.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have had this error and I did all what were described above and even more, but I found another solution. So, I just want to share that even if you have already fixed it because people will see your post first when they get into searching answer.

Here, tou can see error which I got:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the 
google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at 
https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) 
or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.8.0.
```

Here is the build.gradle (app level)

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
  compileSdkVersion 26
 defaultConfig {
     applicationId "idoston.com.firebaseauthenticationandroid"
     minSdkVersion 17
     targetSdkVersion 26
     versionCode 1
     versionName "1.0"
     testInstrumentationRunner 
     "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
     }
     buildTypes {
      release {
         minifyEnabled false
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
        'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
     }
 }

 dependencies {
     implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
     implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
     testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
     androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
     androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
  core:3.0.1'
     compile 'com.android.support:percent:26.1.0'
     compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
     compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.2'
  }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Solution is that : you need to delete which is in the last line:

```
     apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I hope this answer will probably help someone in the future.